# How do I make sure my local area connection never goes down?

Tags: wireless-networking

I've made a local area connection with the *netsh wlan* commands, but found that either after a restart or just an extended period of time the connection just wasn't there anymore, nor did it show up as a profile when I used command prompt to search for it again.

So taking some tips from other users' questions I've reordered adaptor priorities so wireless is highest, and I've also made sure that the power management settings aren't ever going to disable the wifi card. After doing these things I've remade the network.

Have I taken care of everything or are there still other things that could cause the network to not be there again? (Ps. I checked services and I don't have that annoying *autoswitch* one some Dell users were complaining about)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because netsh apply the commands but dont save them. You need to explicity make a profile using the GUI for those configurations to persist after reboots/shutdowns.

Another way to do this is to create the xml profiles programatically in a cmd.exe script.

take this XML profile as example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>SampleWPAPSK</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>SampleWPAPSK</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <autoSwitch>false</autoSwitch>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPAPSK</authentication>
                <encryption>TKIP</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

You must write a bat file that outputs a profile in similar format, to a file with xml extension, then while on netsh issue :

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="<filename>" user=all
```

where  is the name of the xml file containning network info.

Comment: Haha I have no idea about most of what you said but I was able to make the network persistent by adding the 'keyusage=persistent' term at the end, and writing a BAT file that starts the hostednetwork each time I log in. However I am still having trouble with sharing the connection to devices. Sharing will not turn on for that 'adapter'. It says "null" when trying. Do you have any ideas why? Is it something to do with how I made the network?

Comment: Oh sorry man I got it. For some reason I thought I had to enable sharing of the ethernet via the virtual network properties, but you have to enable sharing via the ethernet properties and set the virtual network you want to share it though, then everything works fine. And now it seemingly will continue to persist and work fine forever. --- If you want to add this extra stuff for people to your answer I'll mark it as accepted solution.